# When custom mapping is set for :cn, :cp vim doesn't expand the fold that contains an error

Tags: vim, code-folding

I have noticed that when I use `:cn` `:cp` directly, vim always expands folds for me. But when I set my custom mapping to call `:cn` like `:map <leader>n :cn<cr>`, vim doesn't expand foldings when I use `<leader>n` in this case, I have to move horizontally after using that hotkey to unfold. I could script moving horizontally as well, but I still would like to understand why vim doesn't do that for me.
My `foldopen` setting contains `quickfix`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [vim email archive](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Bug-cn-doesn-t-open-folds-when-rhs-of-map-td1198755.html).

This is the correct behavior and that you are supposed to open folds manually if you put `:cn` or `:cp` into mappings. The solution was to add [`zv`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#zv) to the end of the mappings.

So your maps should look like this

```
noremap <leader>n :cn<CR>zv
```

Note: I change map to noremap because noremap stops recursive mappings whereas map allows for it.